# Can't open VSCode with other user

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, sudo

Well basically i created another user, and i'm tring to open a node project, but i can't use "code ." (i think it's because vscode is installed in the other user, but idk) without having the following error:

```
~/amq-javascript-2.5.0/node_modules/rhea$ code .
```

> **2020/02/12 10:02:20.859002 cmd_run.go:884: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot create "/home/amq-broker/snap/code/24": mkdir /home/amq-broker/snap: permission denied
>       cannot create user data directory: /home/amq-broker/snap/code/24: Permission denied**

*I already tryed with sudo, and got this:*

```
~/amq-javascript-2.5.0/node_modules/rhea$ sudo code .
```

> **You are trying to start vscode as a super user which is not recommended. If you really want to, you must specify an alternate user data directory using the --user-data-dir argument.**

I'm kinda lost here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I was able to finally get it to work by running ...

```
sudo code . --user-data-dir='.'
```

**OR**

`sudo code --user-data-dir /home/fregie/.config/Code/` doesn't work because it needs to be a new user data directory, one whose permissions are not as restrictive as `~/.config.`

This should work for example:

```
sudo code --user-data-dir /home/fregie/.code-root-user-data
```

Note that once we reshuffle the configuration directories this will no longer be necessary to explicitly indicate the root user data dir

Comment: it didn't worked, it didn't displayed any kind of error so far, but just when i execute this command , then it returns nothing...

Comment: you have to pass the directory also replace `' . '` with your directory. I have edited my post and update the answer please try with that may be that solve your problem.Thanks